# Git - Find which apps in repo have changed

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a very large repository that contains many apps/services. For example there are windows services written in C#, a JS/HTML web client, node apps, and other apps.

I want to programmatically find which of these need to be deployed when I tag a new release, based on the diff with the previous tag.

For some apps it is as simple as checking for changes in a subfolder of the repo. For example, the web client is all in `src/clients/web`. But the C# services use some shared C# libraries, which are not in the folder for those services. These dependencies can change over time, so I can only really rely on references in the `csproj` files.

Is there a general (or partial) solution for this problem?

Comment: You can defiantly script for this. Using "git diff --name-only <old tag> <new tag> <repo-root-path>" you will get a list of all the files that change between the tags. From there on, you can run whatever regex on the list to figure out what fits each project re-deployment criteria.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution to that problem would be to use:

- one Git repository per program/library/module
- one parent repository referencing those repos [as **submodules**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

That way, when you put a new tag to the parent repository, you can:

- first do a `git submodule update -remote` to ensure you have the laster (master) of all submodules
- recompile/test to ensure this is the right state you want to tag
- do a `git diff` with the previous tag to see immediately which sub-repository has changed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brute force solution, which is to build twice, looking for changed file timestamps:

```
git checkout <old tag>
msbuild ...
record_all_final_outputs_timestamps > old_timestamps.txt
git checkout <new tag>
msbuild ...
record_all_final_outputs_timestamps > new_timestamps.txt
diff old_timestamps.txt new_timestamps.txt
```

The diff will show you all libraries that actually changed after the incremental build.  C# has a relatively fast build, which may make this method acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all files that may indicate the necessity to redeploy are tracked by git, this is actually quite easy. As already mentioned by Yazeed Sabri in the comments, you can get the full list of modified, added or removed files by executing:

```
git diff --name-only <oldtag> <newtag>
```

Add `-z` to delimit file names with a NUL byte instead of the default newline; this also prevents git from quoting any "unusual" characters in path names.

You can further refine the list of files by providing one or more paths:

```
git diff --name-only <oldtag> <newtag> -- <path_1> <path_2> <path_n>
```

This will only return those files below one of the `<path>`s you provided. Note that the `<path>`s on the command line are relative to the current working directory, however the paths that `git diff` outputs are relative to the root of the git repository.

If you're only interested in the fact that something changed, but not what exactly, you can silence `git diff` and use its exit status like this (shell):

```sh
if ! git diff --quiet "$oldtag" "$newtag" -- src/app_1 app_1.csproj
then
    redeploy app_1
fi
```

Note the `!` here; `git diff --quiet` exits with 0 (= success in shell logic) if the paths provided *did not change* between the given tags, but we want to redeploy when they did. (This behavior is consistent with the standard Linux `diff` command.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use @VonC's suggested layout but with the repo you've got, core commands are what you want, `git diff-tree` doesn't automatically recurse for you so it'll just list which top-level entries have changed:

```
git diff-tree @ @~
```

possibly with `--name-only` if you don't need to check which entries are directories. To do the above in a repo where you've also got toplevel files you want to ignore,

```
git diff-tree @ @~ | awk '$1":"$2 ~ /:04/'
```